# Возможно ли в js наследование части массива

Tags: javascript, прототипное-наследование

У меня есть функция конструктор create_creature которая создает объекты:

```
var cr = new Creature();
// установка параметров
return cr
```

В функции Creature хранятся значения по умолчанию, которые я устанавливаю через

`Creature.prototype.text =  ["","","",""];`

И потом функцией конструктором пытаюсь присвоить значения по отдельным значениям массива:

```
cr.text[0] = "Текст1";
cr.text[1] = "Текст2";
cr.text[2] = "Текст3";
```

В результате функция create_creature, работает совсем не так как задумано и изменяет значения по умолчанию в прототипе Creature. То есть, при попытке создания нового объекта и присваивания дочернему объекту значения параметра только по некоторым индексам массива, изменяется весь массив уже в родителе объекта.

Я конечно понимаю, что эта проблема решается указанием в конструкторе изменения всего массива:

```
cr.text = ["Текст1","Текст2","Текст3"]
```

Но у меня может быть очень большой массив с значениями text и каждый раз полностью передавать его потомку будет довольно накладно. А перспектива создания кучи бесполезных переменных с текстом text1, text2, text3 .... text 500, тоже не радует.

Возможно ли, в функции конструкторе изменять только некоторые индексы в массиве потомка, что бы остальные брались из массива родителя? (и не вызывали его порчи)

Comment: В JavaScript вы можете обращаться к свойствам объекта как через точку (`cr.text`), так и через квадратные скобки: `cr["text"]`. В качестве костыля это поможет не мучаться с полями с разными названиями.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, "унаследовать" лишь кусок массива нельзя - вы либо берёте его целиком из родителя, либо копируете к себе. Кажется, что самое близкое, что можно - это проэмулировать массив при помощи объекта с кучей свойств.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Попробую автоматизированное создание свойств через цикл с cr.text[i], так наверное будет удобней.